# How to get a list off all Jenkins project types

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to get a list of all project/job types of the current Jenkins instace, similar to the static `Builder.all()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question answered, `Items.all()` is similar to `Builder.all()`.

A function to return all project type display names would be

```
private List<String> getAvailableJobTypes() {
    List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
    for ( TopLevelItemDescriptor tliDescriptor : Items.all() ) {
        types.add( tliDescriptor.getDisplayName());
    }
    return types;
}
```